# "Unfortunately app has stopped" error with CVS project and two different IDEs

Tags: android

I have got a weird problem with a CVS project I am working on in a group at University. We have an Android project, a simple polling app. At the beginning a user has to log in to the app with a username and a password. It is actually working on all people in that group except for me. The only difference between us is that I am using IntelliJ Idea 12 Community Edition and all other eclipse. In my specific case it just crashes after I have put in the user and pw and push the log in button. It tries to load the app and immediately throws an "Unfortunately 'app' has stopped" exception.

I guess it has something to do with libraries or maybe the .classpath file of eclipse? I dont really know how well the two IDE's work together?! I read its no problem to use both with CVS.

I have set up eclipse, too. The error appears as well?! I have no clues why that doesnt work just for me?! ...

Here is the logcat output (filter on errors and 'feedback'):

```
 07-16 22:30:35.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2223): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity `enter code here`ComponentInfo{de.unikassel.feedbackclient/de.unikassel.feedbackclient.MainActivity}: `enter code here`java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.unikassel.feedbackclient.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:72)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    ... 11 more
```

And AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.unikassel.feedbackclient"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="de.unikassel.feedbackclient.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="de.unikassel.feedbackclient.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="de.unikassel.feedbackclient.AdminActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_admin" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="de.unikassel.feedbackclient.PollActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_open_poll" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="de.unikassel.feedbackclient.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and my App.iml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="EclipseModuleManager" forced_jdk="true">
    <conelement value="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES" />
    <src_description expected_position="1">
      <src_folder value="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" expected_position="0" />
      <src_folder value="file://$MODULE_DIR$/gen" expected_position="1" />
      <src_folder value="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK" expected_position="2" />
      <src_folder value="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES" expected_position="3" />
    </src_description>
  </component>
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="android" name="Android">
      <configuration />
    </facet>
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="false">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/bin/classes" />
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/gen" isTestSource="false" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="Android 4.2.2 Platform" jdkType="Android SDK" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="module-library" exported="">
      <library>
        <CLASSES>
          <root url="jar://$MODULE_DIR$/libs/android-support-v4.jar!/" />
        </CLASSES>
        <JAVADOC />
        <SOURCES />
      </library>
    </orderEntry>
  </component>
</module>
```

thx for help...

Edit: according to the logcat and the exception thrown in mainactivity I paste the code of it here too...

```
package de.unikassel.feedbackclient;

import java.util.Locale;

import de.unikassel.feedbackclient.R;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;

/**
 * Main Screen where all polls are shown in a tab layout.
 * 
 */
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * Define the number of shown tabs in Tab-Bar.
     */
    private final int NUMTABS = 3;

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    /**
     * Method will be called when Activity will be created by
     * Android OS.
     * 
     * @param Bundle savedInstanceState
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i)).setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method is called to create the options menu for given activity.
     * 
     * @param Menu menu
     * @return boolean
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Method is called if a tab from tab-view is selected.
     * 
     * @param ActionBar.Tab tab
     * @param FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction
     */
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    /**
     * Method is called if a tab from tab-view is unselected (switched to next tab, etc.).
     * 
     * @param ActionBar.Tab tab
     * @param FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction
     */
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * Method is called if a tab from tab-view is reselected (switched back from other tab, etc.).
     * 
     * @param ActionBar.Tab tab
     * @param FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction
     */
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        /**
         * 
         * @param fm FragmentManager
         */
        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            ListFragment fragment =  new ListSectionFragment();

            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return NUMTABS;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
     * displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    }
}
```

Problem solved... the actionbars caused the problem. Following will fix it...

In MainActivity.java after onCreate has to be:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: Looks like somewhere in your project is something that says `enter code here` and you forgot to enter some code.

Comment: it is running if you plug a mobile device in to USB and use it for testing...

Comment: So it crashes only in the emulator? You should put details like that in your question.

Comment: yes, I figured out that it works with mobile devices later on...

Comment: Your logcat says you're getting a NullPointer on line 72(somewhere in `onCreate()`). Which line is that?

Comment: Problem solved... it seems there was a problem with the actionbar

Comment: You should write that up as an answer instead of putting it in the question body. That way it can be accepted and won't stay open forever.